# Convert number to date format using Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am reading data from a text file with more that 14000 rows and there is a column which has eight (08) digit numbers in it. The format for some of the rows are like:

- 01021943
- 02031944
- 00041945
- 00001946

The problem is that when I use to_date function it converts the datatype of the date from object to int64 but I want it to be datetime. Second by using the to_datetime function the dates like

- 00041945 becomes 41945
- 00001946 becomes 1946 and hence I cannot properly format them

Comment: What are these numbers ? seconds, minutes from certain date, etc. ?!

Comment: The numbers are
01 as day (First two from left)
02 as month (Middle Two)
1946 as Year(Last Four from right)

Comment: But you can't have 00 as the day of the month or 00 as the month of the year, can you?

Comment: Your months start at 0? Why can't you slice the string into the appropriate substrings?

Comment: I know but unfortunately the file which I have with me is showing and it has very bad data in it...

Comment: What output are you expecting? And, you say "some of the rows" look like that? What do other rows look like, and how do you handle those?

Comment: Are you possibly using the `pandas` module here? The mention of `int64` and `to_datetime` seems to suggest so...

Comment: Yes I am using pandas here

Comment: @cricket_007 I have more than 14k rows and most of the rows are fine like 10121946 or in proper two digits for day two for month and four for year but there are a handful amount of rows may be more than 4k in the format where either day or month are showing 00 or 0000 in the data along with the year

Comment: and I want to show the date as 10/12/1946 or something like that

Comment: @Baig what do you want to do with these values... for instance - are you going to be manipulating them as dates or just displaying them in a reasonable format? What should 00001946 become - could you assume it's 01011946? Is there a custom default you could use for "missing"/"invalid" values etc...?

Comment: @JonClements I am not sure but I think the best way is to put NaT at the moment and at least I know that these rows have bad data and can play around with them later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add parameter `dtype` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for converting column `col` to `string` and then use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameters `format` for specify formatting and `errors='coerce'` - because bad dates, which are converted to `NaT`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""col
01021943
02031944
00041945
00001946"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), dtype={'col': 'str'})

df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')

print (df)
         col
0 1943-02-01
1 1944-03-02
2        NaT
3        NaT

print (df.dtypes)
col    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Thanks [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38851091/convert-number-to-date-format-using-python#comment65067594_38851500) for another solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""col_name
01021943
02031944
00041945
00001946"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 converters={'col_name': lambda dt: pd.to_datetime(dt, format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')})

print (df)
    col_name
0 1943-02-01
1 1944-03-02
2        NaT
3        NaT

print (df.dtypes)
col_name    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: You can also throw the conversion in on loading instead of post load if required, eg: `df = pd.read_csv('somefile', converters={'col_name': lambda dt: pd.to_datetime(dt, format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')})`

Comment: Yes, it is another solution, thank you. I add it to answer.

Comment: (Although the OP does mention having an NaT value and being able to play around with values later - so it looks like keeping the original and creating an additional column is probably the best way to go)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael & JonClements for your solutions. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As a first guess solution you could just parse it as a string into a datetime instance. Something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

EXAMPLE = u'01021943'

dt = datetime(int(EXAMPLE[4:]), int(EXAMPLE[2:4]), int(EXAMPLE[:2]))
```

...not caring very much about performance issues.

Comment: @JonClements You're right but that's about validation not about the algorithm. You can't allow 0-day or 0-month objects as dates.

Comment: Indeed - however that's also what `pandas.to_datetime` effectively does. So it appears the OP might be after something that can handle/make sense/reasonable defaults from them...

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

def to_date(num_str):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(num_str,"%d%m%Y")
```

Note this will also throw exceptions for zero values because the expected behavior is not clear for this input.
If you want a different behavior for zero values, you can implement it with `try & except`,
for example, if you want to get `None` for zero values you can do:

```
def to_date(num_str):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(num_str,"%d%m%Y")
    except ValueError, e:
        return None
```